# AWS SAM YAML - Attach same policy multiple times, or multiple tables on same DynamoDB policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

Having trouble getting the role to have access to two tables. Example YAML for template.yaml:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: path/to/something
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Events:
        Get:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /path/to/other/thing
            Method: post
      Policies:
        DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName:
            table1
            table2
```

I need this function to be able to read/write on table1 and table2, but this doesn't work. I tried:

```
- table1
- table2
```

But that doesn't work either. Also tried:

```
Policies:
  - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
    TableName:
      table1
  - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
    TableName:
      table2
```

But that errors out as well. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What error do you have? Looks like you miss the indentation to the `TableName`, try this instead:

```
Policies:
 - DynamoDBCrudPolicy: 
     TableName: table1
 - DynamoDBCrudPolicy: 
     TableName: table2
```

PS: I could have write this into the comment but the code wasn't formatting properly

Comment: This is what did it. I'm not a YAML expert. If you edit yours to align the first "- DynamoDBCrudPolicy" all the way to the left I can accept the answer. So basically, I needed to put the "-" under the "P" in "Policies", and then I had the "TableName:" rows indented 4 spaces, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is to create a role for your lambda function like so:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: path/to/something
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Events:
        Get:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /path/to/other/thing
            Method: post
      Role: !GetAtt MyDynamoDBRole.Arn
```

And then attach a policy to that role. Something like this:

```
  MyDynamoDBRole:    
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: "myDynamoDBPolicy"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "dynamodb:BatchGetItem"
                  - "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"
                  - "dynamodb:PutItem"
                  - "dynamodb:GetItem"
                  - "dynamodb:Scan"
                  - "dynamodb:Query"
                  - "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
                  - "dynamodb:UpdateTable"
                  - "dynamodb:GetRecords"
                Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/table1"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - dynamodb.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

*Please note:* that you might need to tweak specific permissions to suit your use case, the code above is just an example to illustrate the construct that I am suggesting.

Comment: That's fine if I wanted to create the role; I was just trying to do it using the predefined policies within SAM, since SAM is billed as being able to make serverless infrastructure easier to roll out. I guess I was looking for a way to do it without having to write my own policy and instead just use the "DynamoDBCrudPolicy" predefined policy. I just need the function to be able to access 2 tables instead of 1, so is there a way for that policy to access 2 tables, or to attach the policy twice?